# Throwing to Promise.all([]) catch block if each promise already has a catch block?

Tags: javascript, promise

I thought that this would throw an error in the `Promise.all` catch block, but it never gets that far?

I'm trying to understand how I can handle the rejected promise at the call and also at `Promise.all`.

```
const apiCallOne = new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
  resolve('Resolved !!!')
)).then(console.log)
  .catch(console.warn);

const apiCallTwo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
  reject('Rejected !!!')
)).then(console.log)
  .catch(console.warn);

Promise.all([apiCallOne, apiCallTwo])
  .then(value => console.log('all', value))
  .catch(err => console.error('error', err));
```

Will `Promise.all` ever hit it's catch block?

Comment: I've been testing this in the console and I can't get the `Promise.all` catch block to be hit, unless I remove the catch block from the rejected promise `apiCallTwo`

Comment: *"I'm trying to understand how I can handle the rejected promise at the call and also at Promise.all."* what yre you trying to build here? why would you want to catch an error that has already been catched *(and therefore is no longer an error)*. Think of nested try-catch blocks: `try { try { } catch(err){ } } catch(err){ }` blocks, because that's what this is.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't the `catch` will swallow the errors and like you said `Promise.all` catch block will never be called, the following will work according to your expectations

```
const apiCallOne = new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
  resolve('Resolved !!!')
)).then(console.log)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.warn(err)
    throw err
  });

const apiCallTwo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
  reject('Rejected !!!')
)).then(console.log)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.warn(err)
    throw err
  });

Promise.all([apiCallOne, apiCallTwo])
  .then(value => console.log('all', value))
  .catch(err => console.error('error', err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle them when you call `Promise.all`, there is no need to handle them before you execute the requests because we want to run them in parallel and cancel all if there is an error.

```
const apiCallOne = new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
  resolve('Resolved !!!')
))

const apiCallTwo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
  reject('Rejected !!!')
))

Promise.all([apiCallOne, apiCallTwo])
  .then(value => console.log('all', value))
  .catch(err => console.error('error', err));
```